# Regex set pattern by considering parameter as text

Tags: c#, regex

I have an a string that user may set and I would like to use that string inside pattern.

The pattern shall look like this "." + inputStr + "."

Though what if uses has regex specific charaters inside input. Pattern will break wouldnt it?

How can I create a pattern so that regex ignores what is inside inputStr?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Regex.Escape(inputStr);
```

This should escape the string of any characters that would muck with your `RegEx` (and instead interpret those characters literally).